# Daemon in Android

Tags: android, daemon

Is there any registration process for creating a daemon application with Google or any other registration site?

We are making an alert application that runs in the background. Can we create a daemon or is there some another method provided?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called ["Service"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use. Each service class must have a corresponding [`<service>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestService) declaration in its package's `AndroidManifest.xml`. Services can be started with [`Context.startService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)) and [`Context.bindService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int)).
>
> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work...

Comment: @lindenrovio What stops you from creating a thread for your service?

Comment: There is a difference - A `Service` is subject to getting killed off by the OS in a way that a true daemon wouldn't be outside of highly exceptional conditions.  You couldn't reliably use a `Service` to run a webserver, for instance

Answer (score -5):

No, you can't. Even if you're a registered Android developer.

Google does not want anybody except their own employees writing system code. That's why gaining root access on android devices is so challenging. Yes, part of the reason is that it makes Android reeeaaall secure...but it also means that Android effectively becomes a closed system that only Google employees can access.

Sorry.